# how to load html page with javascript async calls using html-imports

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-component, html-imports

im trying to load HTML page it has it is own data and ajax calls to render a view using `html-import`, but the issue is when the import happens the view yet not finish rendering, is there is a way to know when the view is finished calling and rendering  all its element

```js
(function(){
 function createLauncherPanel() {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("class", "launcher-panel");
        div.classList.add("hidden");
        div.appendChild(createLauncherLink(div));

        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);

        return div;
    }

    function createLauncherLink(container) {
        var link = document.createElement("link");

        link.setAttribute("rel", "import");
        link.setAttribute("href", "path-to-htmlpage-with-data-load -asynchronously-with-json-feed-and-view-to-render");

     
        console.log('container',container);
        link.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  // all imports loaded
        console.log(e);
         console.log('link',link);
         console.log(link.import);
          // #ele is the element i need to get from the imported page - but sence this element is not rendered yet because of the lateinse of rendering and network calls , this will return null 
   container.appendChild(link.import.querySelector('#ele'));
});
        

        return link;
    }
    

    createLauncherPanel();
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcomponentsjs/1.0.13/webcomponents-lite.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
     
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, worssld</h1>
    <div id="ff"></div>
<script src="sc.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do show some code or face the downvotes and closing. There is not effort shown here at all

Comment: added some code to explain the issue , @mplungjan

Comment: As I said it is an HTML page comes from a third party, when `onload` fires not all the elements are rendered yet it returns only empty `body`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the `onload` event as it will fire when everything has finished loading.

> The onload event occurs when an object has been loaded.
>
> onload is most often used within the  element to execute a
>   script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including
>   images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

Comment: I tried `onload` still not working because what I'm loading is an HTML. so at the time onload fires the page dom ready but not yet render all data comes from the feed with its dom elements,  page.which i use to load it using `iframe` , now I'm trying to move away from the `iframe`